# Distributing identical pencils among students

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we distribute $10$ identical pencils among $4$ students? Every distribution is possible including that one student can get all pencils.

As I know, that can be done by $(4)^{10}$ as the first pencil can be given to one of the students, and then the same for the second and so on ... that can be $(4)^{10}$. Is that right?  But I think that way can be applicable if the pencils are distinguishable!!  I am not sure about it.

Comment: You need to use stars and bars as pencils are identical. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: @MathLover  Could you please explain what you means by stars and bars ?

Comment: What you are trying to find is equivalent to  finding solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$ where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are non-negative integers. You may want to go through the link I shared.

Comment: I got it, you mean it will be $C^{10+4-1}_4 = 286$ is that right ?

Comment: It will be ${{10+4-1} \choose {4-1}}$

Comment: OK .. thank you